# Meteor: Uncaught Error: Must be attached (delete function)

Tags: javascript, meteor, uncaught-exception, typeerror

I have an error in the console every time I'm deleting an item (List) in my Meteor application. 
The error in the console is:

> domrange.js:337 Uncaught Error: Must be attached

Here is the function, I can't understand where come from this error:

**Lists.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
   'lists.remove'(listId) {
       check(listId, String);

       const list = Lists.findOne(listId);
       if (list.owner !== this.userId) {
           throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
       }
       Tasks.remove({"listId": listId});
       Lists.remove(listId);
   },
```

All is working properly in the application but do you know where this error can come from ?

Ps: I'm using Blaze if it can help

thanks

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue with meteor - https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2981

Comment: thanks @Craicerjack, I've read this before, just the topic is from 2015 so I thought there was maybe a new solution. There seems to not be THE solution, just some patchs, I don't know how to use the Meteor.defer() solution with my code.

Comment: You can create 2 versions of the method, one for the client and one for the server (or not implement the method on the client at all). You can either create 2 different methods or use `this.isSimulation` to only run parts of the code on the client/server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found the solution adding a Meteor.isServer or better if (!this.isSimulation) (@MasterAM solution):

```
    'lists.remove'(listId) {
        check(listId, String);

        const list = Lists.findOne(listId);
        if (list.owner !== this.userId) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
        }
        if (!this.isSimulation) {
            Tasks.remove({"listId": listId});
            Lists.remove(listId);
        }
    },
```

I edited the working code with the help of @MasterAM It'w working now! No Console error anymore.

Comment: `this.isSimulation` evaluates to `true` on the client (in a stub), so if you want to prevent this from happening in stubs, you should use `if (!this.isSimulation)`.

Comment: Oh okey I see! Thank you very much for the explanations @MasterAM :)